Why is water accumulating around the post between my patio doors?
I had my patio doors replaced at the end of May this year. I have been having issues with water seeping in at the bottom of the center post. The center post they installed was a 4x4 pressure treated. It was sitting directly on the concrete. Days after rain or extreme temperatures, we would start seeing water seeping inside the patio. The 4x4 post was wrapped with an aluminum wrap.
Not knowing what was causing this, they came back out and completely removed everything, including all frames. There were no indications of water leaking down from the roof. Everything above the frame was dry. When they removed the wrap from the pressure-treated post, the post was soaking wet.
Not knowing where the water was coming from, they rebuilt everything, but this time, they used a galvanized standoff 4x4 post base secured to the concrete and sealed all around. They then put in a cedar 4x4 and aluminum wrap, and everything was caulked and sealed.
It's been about a month, and I'm now seeing signs of water seeping out. I can hear water inside squishing around if I take my knuckles and knock on the aluminum.
This is located in Michigan, and it faces directly west. During the sun, it gets hot.
I've attached two pictures, one normal and one with a thermal, and a video just so you can hear what I hear.
I think this is a thermal issue, with cold temps at night and hot sun, and air gaps between the wrap and the post create condensation, and the more frequently it happens, the more moisture the board is storing when it gets warmer and cools at night just to sweat the next day again.
I've been asking them to fix this, and they have no idea what could be causing this since they can not find a direct water leak.
They do not seem to think my suggestion of this being a thermal thing is possible.
What could be causing this or, better, how to prevent this from happening?
Pictures and video/sound clip

What does your roof overhang look like?  Did they install a header flashing?  Does the outside surface of the patio doors get wet when it rains?

Sounds like too much water in too short a period of time to be condensation.  What is your RH inside your house?  Does the interior of your window frame sweat ?

I added a picture of when they removed the old sliding patio doors. Yes, when it rains, water will directly hit the patio doors.

To help give more of a visual, I uploaded many more pictures with captions on them.

Is the cedar 4x4 kiln dried? If not, they can hold a lot of water.

I do not know if it was or not. I can push on the trim and hear the water squishing around.
